# How to define '@ IN MX 0 @' in easydns?

Tags: dns, mx

I am not entirely sure how to add this entry into easydns. I have contacted their support but I still hear nothing after days.

For some reason my hosting company needed to switch the hardware of our server. They sent me these info

```
@       IN MX   0 @
@       IN A    157.28.29.27
www     IN A    157.28.29.27
*       IN A    157.28.29.27
```

I don't know how to map the first entry into the easydns interface

Here is the easydns MX interface:

[image]

I am not sure if it is the problem that is stopping me from receiving emails for my domain

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a DNS entry *mail.example.com* with a **A** record *157.28.29.27*

Then in your MX records set up *@.example.com* > *mail.example.com* with a PREF of 0

What this is doing is the MX record is specifying that mail is handled by *mail.example.com*

Then your A record directs *mail.example.com* to correct IP address.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! A followup question: What does PREF mean?

Comment: @AnthonyKong PREF is the preferred order that SMTP servers are tried for delivery. For example, you can have several servers with different PREF values so that there is a backup server.

Comment: Just as a side note, I would set up mail.example.com using a CNAME. It is one more call, but safer when you need to make a quick DNS change. Cheers!!

Comment: @AnthonyKong Anything mate! This is what we do. We really like helping people here.

Comment: @closetnoc I agree, the reason I set them up that way is because I often have customers with the website at somewhere like Weebly and the mail with me.  So a CNAME for mail.example.com won't work.

Comment: @Steve Excellent point. I made the comment to help educate others who may come along. Cheers!!